# GitHub actions - use a custom container registry

Tags: github, containers, github-actions, docker-registry, docker-image

When using GitHub actions (for example CodeQL code scanning) you can specify a container image in which the action would run, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainerimage

In the docs it says:

> The Docker image to use as the container to run the action. The value can be the Docker Hub image name or a registry name.

I need to specify an image which resides on a private registry, not in (the public) Docker Hub. The docs seem to suggest it is possible ("or a registry name") but I am not sure if and how I could specify a private image (I refer to the private image in docker as `https://my.server.com:1234/dir/image-name:latest`).

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: In the docs page you referenced they even have example there: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-20 - any issues with it?

Comment: @taleodor: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Put this in an answer so I can accept it, please.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested the option that you've mentioned but unfortunately it is not working.
Planning to get support from GitHub to try and figure out if it's possible. (Have a corporate account)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31253993)